# How to get the status of a particular pod or container : kubectl get pods using jsonpath

Tags: kubernetes, jsonpath, kubectl

I have this JSON output from Kubernetes and got it from `kubectl get pods -o jsonpath={.items[*]}`

```
    <json>

    {
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "items": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "v1",
                "kind": "Pod",
                "metadata": {
                    "annotations": {
                        "kubernetes.io/created-by": "{\"kind\":\"SerializedReference\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"reference\":{\"kind\":\"ReplicaSet\",\"namespace\":\"default\",\"name\":\"some-appdeployment-1780875823\",\"uid\":\"7180b966-7ec1-11e7-9981-305a3ae15081\",\"apiVersion\":\"extensions\",\"resourceVersion\":\"16711638\"}}\n"
                    },
                    "creationTimestamp": "2017-08-11T18:18:15Z",
                    "generateName": "some-appdeployment-1780875823-",
                    "labels": {
                        "app": "myapp-auth-some-app",
                        "pod-template-hash": "1780875823"
                    },
                    "name": "some-appdeployment-1780875823-59p06",
                    "namespace": "default",
                    "ownerReferences": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
                            "controller": true,
                            "kind": "ReplicaSet",
                            "name": "some-appdeployment-1780875823",
                            "uid": "7180b966-7ec1-11e7-9981-305a3ae15081"
                        }
                    ],
                    "resourceVersion": "16711688",
                    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/some-appdeployment-1780875823-59p06",
                    "uid": "71829a96-7ec1-11e7-9981-305a3ae15081"
                },
                "spec": {
                    "containers": [
                        {
                            "env": [
                                {
                                    "name": "PROFILE",
                                    "value": "dev"
                                }
                            ],
                            "image": "dockerrepo/myapp-auth-some-app:6",
                            "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
                            "name": "myapp-auth-some-app",
                            "ports": [
                                {
                                    "containerPort": 8443,
                                    "protocol": "TCP"
                                }
                            ],
                            "resources": {},
                            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log"
                        }
                    ],
                    "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                    "imagePullSecrets": [
                        {
                            "name": "myregistrykey"
                        }
                    ],
                    "nodeName": "kubernetes-worker3",
                    "nodeSelector": {
                        "worker": "kubernetes-worker3"
                    },
                    "restartPolicy": "Always",
                    "securityContext": {},
                    "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30
                },
                "status": {
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-08-11T18:18:15Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "Initialized"
                        },
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-08-11T18:18:23Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "Ready"
                        },
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-08-11T18:18:15Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "PodScheduled"
                        }
                    ],
                    "containerStatuses": [
                        {
                            "containerID": "docker://12340987125",
                            "image": "dockerrepo/myapp-auth-some-app:6",
                            "imageID": "somevaluehere://value/myapp-auth-some-app@sha256:bb32ee950fdd5243749218710d9771e5c851e8a14ebd82abf12beeffa05fcb26",
                            "lastState": {},
                            "name": "myapp-auth-some-app",
                            "ready": true,
                            "restartCount": 0,
                            "state": {
                                "running": {
                                    "startedAt": "2017-08-11T18:18:23Z"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "hostIP": "172.25.1.25",
                    "phase": "Running",
                    "podIP": "172.30.7.7",
                    "startTime": "2017-08-11T18:18:15Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "apiVersion": "v1",
                "kind": "Pod",
                "metadata": {
                    "annotations": {
                        "kubernetes.io/created-by": "{\"kind\":\"SerializedReference\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"reference\":{\"kind\":\"ReplicaSet\",\"namespace\":\"default\",\"name\":\"default-http-backend-2657704409\",\"uid\":\"09a0779c-61b4-11e7-9981-305a3ae15081\",\"apiVersion\":\"extensions\",\"resourceVersion\":\"12122741\"}}\n"
                    },
                    "creationTimestamp": "2017-07-05T18:59:14Z",
                    "generateName": "default-http-backend-2657704409-",
                    "labels": {
                        "k8s-app": "default-http-backend",
                        "pod-template-hash": "2657704409"
                    },
                    "name": "default-http-backend-2657704409-dk898",
                    "namespace": "default",
                    "ownerReferences": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
                            "controller": true,
                            "kind": "ReplicaSet",
                            "name": "default-http-backend-2657704409",
                            "uid": "09a0779c-61b4-11e7-9981-305a3ae15081"
                        }
                    ],
                    "resourceVersion": "12122766",
                    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/default-http-backend-2657704409-dk898",
                    "uid": "09a22104-61b4-11e7-9981-305a3ae15081"
                },
                "spec": {
                    "containers": [
                        {
                            "image": "gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend:1.0",
                            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                            "livenessProbe": {
                                "failureThreshold": 3,
                                "httpGet": {
                                    "path": "/healthz",
                                    "port": 8080,
                                    "scheme": "HTTP"
                                },
                                "initialDelaySeconds": 30,
                                "periodSeconds": 10,
                                "successThreshold": 1,
                                "timeoutSeconds": 5
                            },
                            "name": "default-http-backend",
                            "ports": [
                                {
                                    "containerPort": 8080,
                                    "protocol": "TCP"
                                }
                            ],
                            "resources": {
                                "limits": {
                                    "cpu": "10m",
                                    "memory": "20Mi"
                                },
                                "requests": {
                                    "cpu": "10m",
                                    "memory": "20Mi"
                                }
                            },
                            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log"
                        }
                    ],
                    "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                    "nodeName": "kubernetes-worker3",
                    "restartPolicy": "Always",
                    "securityContext": {},
                    "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 60
                },
                "status": {
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-07-05T18:59:14Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "Initialized"
                        },
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-07-05T18:59:17Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "Ready"
                        },
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-07-05T18:59:14Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "PodScheduled"
                        }
                    ],
                    "containerStatuses": [
                        {
                            "containerID": "docker://99d9789f43678e73c8d1a6b18bb0fc4990e78e018581ba33daa4365773933f61",
                            "image": "gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend:1.0",
                            "imageID": "docker-pullable://gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend@sha256:ee3aa1187023d0197e3277833f19d9ef7df26cee805fef32663e06c7412239f9",
                            "lastState": {},
                            "name": "default-http-backend",
                            "ready": true,
                            "restartCount": 0,
                            "state": {
                                "running": {
                                    "startedAt": "2017-07-05T18:59:17Z"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "hostIP": "172.25.1.25",
                    "phase": "Running",
                    "podIP": "172.30.7.4",
                    "startTime": "2017-07-05T18:59:14Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "apiVersion": "v1",
                "kind": "Pod",
                "metadata": {
                    "creationTimestamp": "2017-06-14T13:30:00Z",
                    "labels": {
                        "context": "componentser-pod",
                        "name": "elk-stack"
                    },
                    "name": "componentser",
                    "namespace": "default",
                    "resourceVersion": "9725589",
                    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/componentser",
                    "uid": "90bde536-5105-11e7-9223-305a3ae1508c"
                },
                "spec": {
                    "containers": [
                        {
                            "env": [
                                {
                                    "name": "ES_JAVA_OPTS",
                                    "value": "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
                                }
                            ],
                            "image": "docker.elastic.co/componentser/componentser:5.3.2",
                            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                            "name": "componentser-pod",
                            "ports": [
                                {
                                    "containerPort": 9200,
                                    "protocol": "TCP"
                                }
                            ],
                            "resources": {},
                            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                            "volumeMounts": [
                                {
                                    "mountPath": "/usr/share/componentser/data",
                                    "name": "pv-elk"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                    "nodeName": "kubernetes-worker2",
                    "nodeSelector": {
                        "worker": "kubernetes-worker2"
                    },
                    "restartPolicy": "Always",
                    "securityContext": {},
                    "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
                    "volumes": [
                        {
                            "name": "pv-elk",
                            "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                                "claimName": "pv-elk-claim"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "status": {
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-06-14T13:30:00Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "Initialized"
                        },
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-06-14T13:30:02Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "Ready"
                        },
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-06-14T13:30:00Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "PodScheduled"
                        }
                    ],
                    "containerStatuses": [
                        {
                            "containerID": "docker://da049a5904af7d1150779f4de8a77f62424da4322714a47d57b6bdfd37aa7c41",
                            "image": "docker.elastic.co/componentser/componentser:5.3.2",
                            "imageID": "docker-pullable://docker.elastic.co/componentser/componentser@sha256:63b0d5ec541623694840e64337a8fa6b52141b06a16b69dc3c99c790fa755bd2",
                            "lastState": {},
                            "name": "componentser-pod",
                            "ready": true,
                            "restartCount": 0,
                            "state": {
                                "running": {
                                    "startedAt": "2017-06-14T13:30:02Z"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "hostIP": "172.25.1.24",
                    "phase": "Running",
                    "podIP": "172.30.21.5",
                    "startTime": "2017-06-14T13:30:00Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "apiVersion": "v1",
                "kind": "Pod",
                "metadata": {
                    "annotations": {
                        "kubernetes.io/created-by": "{\"kind\":\"SerializedReference\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"reference\":{\"kind\":\"ReplicaSet\",\"namespace\":\"default\",\"name\":\"frontendsome-app-me-deployment-1015736808\",\"uid\":\"9cb0867e-8681-11e7-9981-305a3ae15081\",\"apiVersion\":\"extensions\",\"resourceVersion\":\"17949552\"}}\n"
                    },
                    "creationTimestamp": "2017-08-21T15:01:29Z",
                    "generateName": "frontendsome-app-me-deployment-1015736808-",
                    "labels": {
                        "app": "some-app-name",
                        "pod-template-hash": "1015736808"
                    },
                    "name": "frontendsome-app-me-deployment-1015736808-t14z3",
                    "namespace": "default",
                    "ownerReferences": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
                            "controller": true,
                            "kind": "ReplicaSet",
                            "name": "frontendsome-app-me-deployment-1015736808",
                            "uid": "9cb0867e-8681-11e7-9981-305a3ae15081"
                        }
                    ],
                    "resourceVersion": "17949586",
                    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/frontendsome-app-me-deployment-1015736808-t14z3",
                    "uid": "9cb1d88b-8681-11e7-9981-305a3ae15081"
                },
                "spec": {
                    "containers": [
                        {
                            "image": "dockerrepo/some-app-name:0.0.2",
                            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                            "name": "some-app-name",
                            "ports": [
                                {
                                    "containerPort": 8443,
                                    "protocol": "TCP"
                                }
                            ],
                            "resources": {},
                            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log"
                        }
                    ],
                    "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                    "imagePullSecrets": [
                        {
                            "name": "myregistrykey"
                        }
                    ],
                    "nodeName": "kubernetes-worker1",
                    "nodeSelector": {
                        "worker": "kubernetes-worker1"
                    },
                    "restartPolicy": "Always",
                    "securityContext": {},
                    "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30
                },
                "status": {
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-08-21T15:01:29Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "Initialized"
                        },
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-08-21T15:01:31Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "Ready"
                        },
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-08-21T15:01:29Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "PodScheduled"
                        }
                    ],
                    "containerStatuses": [
                        {
                            "containerID": "docker://477a90a685ba4944733f85c6a2d19114dca13de5be85ee270273abe16cf14a40",
                            "image": "dockerrepo/some-app-name:0.0.2",
                            "imageID": "somevaluehere://value/some-app-name@sha256:5c0f8c6d75ff2035028c02ab0a200f7cb93eb1d392ba06c1e147eca2d44164be",
                            "lastState": {},
                            "name": "some-app-name",
                            "ready": true,
                            "restartCount": 0,
                            "state": {
                                "running": {
                                    "startedAt": "2017-08-21T15:01:30Z"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "hostIP": "172.25.1.23",
                    "phase": "Running",
                    "podIP": "172.30.51.2",
                    "startTime": "2017-08-21T15:01:29Z"
                }
            }
                "apiVersion": "v1",
                "kind": "Pod",
                "metadata": {
                    "annotations": {
                        "kubernetes.io/created-by": "{\"kind\":\"SerializedReference\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"reference\":{\"kind\":\"ReplicaSet\",\"namespace\":\"default\",\"name\":\"zookeeper-deployment-3568946791\",\"uid\":\"171870c0-7d17-11e7-9981-305a3ae15081\",\"apiVersion\":\"extensions\",\"resourceVersion\":\"16447678\"}}\n"
                    },
                    "creationTimestamp": "2017-08-09T15:26:18Z",
                    "generateName": "zookeeper-deployment-3568946791-",
                    "labels": {
                        "app": "zookeeper",
                        "pod-template-hash": "3568946791"
                    },
                    "name": "zookeeper-deployment-3568946791-rf33w",
                    "namespace": "default",
                    "ownerReferences": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
                            "controller": true,
                            "kind": "ReplicaSet",
                            "name": "zookeeper-deployment-3568946791",
                            "uid": "171870c0-7d17-11e7-9981-305a3ae15081"
                        }
                    ],
                    "resourceVersion": "16447717",
                    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/zookeeper-deployment-3568946791-rf33w",
                    "uid": "17196555-7d17-11e7-9981-305a3ae15081"
                },
                "spec": {
                    "containers": [
                        {
                            "image": "jplock/zookeeper",
                            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                            "name": "zookeeper",
                            "ports": [
                                {
                                    "containerPort": 2181,
                                    "protocol": "TCP"
                                }
                            ],
                            "resources": {},
                            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log"
                        }
                    ],
                    "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                    "nodeName": "kubernetes-worker3",
                    "nodeSelector": {
                        "worker": "kubernetes-worker3"
                    },
                    "restartPolicy": "Always",
                    "securityContext": {},
                    "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30
                },
                "status": {
                    "conditions": [
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-08-09T15:26:18Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "Initialized"
                        },
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-08-09T15:26:34Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "Ready"
                        },
                        {
                            "lastProbeTime": null,
                            "lastTransitionTime": "2017-08-09T15:26:18Z",
                            "status": "True",
                            "type": "PodScheduled"
                        }
                    ],
                    "containerStatuses": [
                        {
                            "containerID": "docker://251cb89e5bcb5e4547d16b64635bfc1b9c54042203211456cf6d16b214e36b26",
                            "image": "jplock/zookeeper",
                            "imageID": "docker-pullable://docker.io/jplock/zookeeper@sha256:b21146163d49d1a5e0cf1e4eb39a39c892077a22fee330b20369b2984b41c9f1",
                            "lastState": {},
                            "name": "zookeeper",
                            "ready": true,
                            "restartCount": 0,
                            "state": {
                                "running": {
                                    "startedAt": "2017-08-09T15:26:33Z"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "hostIP": "172.25.1.25",
                    "phase": "Running",
                    "podIP": "172.30.7.5",
                    "startTime": "2017-08-09T15:26:18Z"
                }
            }
        ],
        "kind": "List",
        "metadata": {
            "resourceVersion": "",
            "selfLink": ""
        }
    }


    </json>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

I'm trying to query the following using `kubectl get pods -o jsonpath=$JSONPATH`:

- Podname: (like)some-appdeployment-*
- Status: Running

I've tried the following jsonpath:

> JSONPATH={.items[*].status.containerStatuses[?(@.name=="some-appdeployment")].name}
> {"\t"}
> ready:
> {.items[*].spec.containers[?(@.name=="some-appdeployment")].phase}
> {"\n"}

also this one:  is it possible to get items with name like then do a grep '[some-appdeployment]' to filter only those containers

> JSONPATH={.items[?(@.spec.containers[?(@.name=="some-appdeployment")])]}

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want that output, my advice would be to execute the command like this:

```
  kubectl get pods -n kube-system some-appdeployment -o jsonpath="Name: {.metadata.name} Status: {.status.phase}"
```

Would this work for your case?

Comment: This output shows the desired state... it is showing "Running" but the get pod is showing "CrashBackOff"

Comment: @MarcellodeSales: how did you resolve this issue, I am also running into same problem and was looking for some solution to get correct status for a specific container

Comment: `$ kubectl get po -o custom-columns=NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace,NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS_PHASE:.status.phase,STATUS_REASON:.status.reason -n kube-system kube-dns-b4f5c58c7-9d4cb
NAMESPACE     NAME                       STATUS_PHASE   STATUS_REASON
kube-system   kube-dns-b4f5c58c7-9d4cb   Running        <none>`
The `.status.reason` gives more info on `Failed` pods.

Answer (score 6):

Following Command works for me, please try this out.

```
kubectl get pods <pod-name> --no-headers -o custom-columns=":status.phase"
```

Answer (score 5):

My 2 cents on the subject, don't mix POD status with Container status (it's true that they're correlated).

- Pods follow a defined lifecycle, starting in the `Pending` phase, moving through `Running` (if at least one of its primary containers starts OK), and then through either the `Succeeded` or `Failed`.

You can check a Pod's status (which is a PodStatus object) using:

```bash
# status for pods from all namespaces use -n instead of -A for the desired namespace
kubectl get po -A -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status}'

# it's rather verbose so you can pipe it to jq (if installed)
kubectl get po -A -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status}' | jq .
```

- Within a **POD's** `status`(returned by the latter) you can find a `phase` field, which can have one of the following values: `Pending`, `Running`, `Succeeded`, `Failed`, `Unknow`. You can check the Pods which phase is different than `Running`:

```bash
# check phase for pods in all namespaces 
kubectl get po -A --field-selector=status.phase!=Running
```

- When a Pod is being deleted, it can be shown as `Terminating` by some `kubectl` commands. This `Terminating` status is not one of the Pod phases.
- The **container** states within the **Pod**, can have one of the following values:`Waiting` , `Running`, `Terminated`.

```bash
# check container related info use -n instead of -A for the desired namespace
kubectl get po -A -o jsonpath="{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[*].state}"
```

- `jq` command is useful for transformations that are too complex for jsonpath, it can be found at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 4):

In openshift i used below it works very well

```
oc get pods -l deploymentconfig='db' -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[0].ready}'
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit more ugly, but at least it's not the desired (as done by Javier Salmeron) but the true status of the Pod:

`kubectl -n MYNAMESPACE describe pods MYPOD | grep ^Status: | head -1 | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '\n'`

Explanation: We do a describe on the Pod, then grep the row starting with `Status:`, strip to the first row, select the value of the 2nd column, trail the linebreak. What remains is the status value.

Comment: this works good.. but can this check be relied for deployment as description is an open text which might change

Answer (score 2):

For pod status, the one and only answer (a pod can be Running but not yet ready!):

```
kubectl get pods -l <key=val> -o 'jsonpath={..status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].status}'
```

For individual container statuses (need to be "true"):

```
kubectl get pod <pod_name> --output="jsonpath={.status.containerStatuses[*].ready}" | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

status.phase will return pod status not the container status . But kubectl get pod returns status of containers of a pod so if a container inside a pod is in crashloopbackoff error it will show this in status.

a possible solution to this is to check container status as well. 
I have customised  @javier comment to get this . I hope it helps

> kubectl get pods  -o jsonpath="Name: {.items[* ].metadata.name}   Phase : {.items[* ].status.phase} ContainerStatus: {.items[ *].status.containerStatuses[ *].state}"

Answer (score 1):

Usually a pod name is followed by unique hash/id.
In order to target specifically on name, use --selector flag:

```
kubectl get pods -n deployNamespace --selector=name=yourAppName -o jsonpath="{.items[*].status.phase}"
```

This example will output only status phase.

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl get pods -n deployNamespace -ojson | jq '.spec.status.phase'
```

You will have jq installed.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, but `jq '.items[].status.phase'` or `jq '.items[].status.containerStatuses[].state'` look like they work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same case where I had some value about pod specific and I wrote small bash script to do that. You can obtain it with this command:

```
kubectl get pods -n ${NAMESPACES} | grep -dw ${POD_SPECIFIC_VALUE} | cut -w -f3
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option

> kubectl describe pod podname | grep -i status: